# Вёрстка: в чём разница между кнопками button и submit

Tags: вёрстка, html

Вёрстка у меня всегда была слабой стороной.
Вот и сейчас не могу понять разницу.
[Здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/type) нашёл описание:
button - кнопка
submit - кнопка для отправки данных.
Судя по всему button тоже можно использовать для передачи данных.
Так в чём же разница?

Comment: Нету здесь уязвимости :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кнопка типа **Submit** сама отправляет данные формы на сервер, а для **Button** это нужно делать вручную.
[link text](http://htmlbook.ru/html/button/type)

Answer (score 5):

```
<input type="submit" value="Отправить"> - просто кнопка
<button type="submit"><b>Отправить</b></button> - контейнер кнопки.
```

По функционалу это одно и тоже. Разница в том, что в контейнер можно запихать любую разметку (в примере теги <b>).

**UPD:** прошу прощения, не до конца вник в вопрос :)

Comment: а еще у баттона по умолчанию тип сабмит. Так что надо специально прописывать

     <button type="button">

Comment: Так в чём разница  применительно к формам?

    <input type="buttom" value="отправить">
    <input type="submit" value="отправить">  
  
в браузере одно и тоже.

Comment: @zenith, вам же сказано что внутри <form>, <submit> сама отправляет запрос на указаный в <form> аттрибут action а <button> нет

Comment: Или вы знаете только HTML? Тогда вам пока рано искать разницу :)

Comment: @Rules спасибо кэп, я ещё вчера галочку поставил.  
Ты прав, только на HTML бекенды и пишу, остальные языки отстой :)

Answer (score 0):

`button` рулит! В неё можно вставить иконку FontAwesome а ещё у неё три типа: `type=button` — обычная кнопка, `type=submit` — сабмит для формы и `type=reset` — обнулить поля в форме. Так что если надо вставить картинку или иконку в кнопку, то лучше `<button></button>`.

Answer (score -1):

сложно сказать на сколько этот вопрос актуальный, но одно верно - в "бутон" можно запихнуть что угодно, ведь это контейнер, а вот с серверной стороной проблемы - нельзя ни повесить обработчики, а если повесишь, то отследить невозможно! пользовался, отдаю предпочтения "инпутам" если это возможно, нет тогда любой контейнер, но не - "бутон"

Comment: Что значит отследить невозможно? Функциональность button полностью аналогична функциональности input, можно прописать точно такие же name и value и всё отлично отслеживать